# Upload multiple files directly to AWS S3 bucket from browser with PHP

Tags: php, ajax, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I need to make a web form capable of uploading multiple files directly to my AWS S3 bucket from browser with PHP.

I came across this nice solution for single file uploads (https://www.sanwebe.com/2015/09/direct-upload-to-amazon-aws-s3-using-php-html):

```
<?php
$access_key         = "iam-user-access-key"; //Access Key
$secret_key         = "iam-user-secret-key"; //Secret Key
$my_bucket          = "mybucket"; //bucket name
$region             = "us-east-1"; //bucket region
$success_redirect   = 'http://'. $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']; //URL to which the client is redirected upon success (currently self) 
$allowd_file_size   = "1048579"; //1 MB allowed Size

//dates
$short_date         = gmdate('Ymd'); //short date
$iso_date           = gmdate("Ymd\THis\Z"); //iso format date
$expiration_date    = gmdate('Y-m-d\TG:i:s\Z', strtotime('+1 hours')); //policy expiration 1 hour from now

//POST Policy required in order to control what is allowed in the request
//For more info http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sigv4-HTTPPOSTConstructPolicy.html
$policy = utf8_encode(json_encode(array(
                    'expiration' => $expiration_date,  
                    'conditions' => array(
                        array('acl' => 'public-read'),  
                        array('bucket' => $my_bucket), 
                        array('success_action_redirect' => $success_redirect),
                        array('starts-with', '$key', ''),
                        array('content-length-range', '1', $allowd_file_size), 
                        array('x-amz-credential' => $access_key.'/'.$short_date.'/'.$region.'/s3/aws4_request'),
                        array('x-amz-algorithm' => 'AWS4-HMAC-SHA256'),
                        array('X-amz-date' => $iso_date)
                        )))); 

//Signature calculation (AWS Signature Version 4)   
//For more info http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/sig-v4-authenticating-requests.html  
$kDate = hash_hmac('sha256', $short_date, 'AWS4' . $secret_key, true);
$kRegion = hash_hmac('sha256', $region, $kDate, true);
$kService = hash_hmac('sha256', "s3", $kRegion, true);
$kSigning = hash_hmac('sha256', "aws4_request", $kService, true);
$signature = hash_hmac('sha256', base64_encode($policy), $kSigning);
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<title>Aws S3 Direct File Uploader</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="http://<?= $my_bucket ?>.s3.amazonaws.com/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="hidden" name="key" value="${filename}" />
<input type="hidden" name="acl" value="public-read" />
<input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Credential" value="<?= $access_key; ?>/<?= $short_date; ?>/<?= $region; ?>/s3/aws4_request" />
<input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Algorithm" value="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256" />
<input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Date" value="<?=$iso_date ; ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="Policy" value="<?=base64_encode($policy); ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Signature" value="<?=$signature ?>" />
<input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="<?= $success_redirect ?>" /> 
<input type="file" name="file" />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
<?php
//After success redirection from AWS S3
if(isset($_GET["key"]))
{
    $filename = $_GET["key"];
    $ext = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    if(in_array($ext, array("jpg", "png", "gif", "jpeg"))){
        echo '<hr />Image File Uploaded : <br /><img src="//'.$my_bucket.'.s3.amazonaws.com/'.$_GET["key"].'" style="width:100%;" />';
    }else{
        echo '<hr />File Uploaded : <br /><a href="http://'.$my_bucket.'.s3.amazonaws.com/'.$_GET["key"].'">'.$filename.'</a>';
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

It works great for it purpose, but I need a solution that will be able to upload multiple uploads at once.

One of the comments on page specifies an approach:

> AWS only allows you to upload one file at a time if uploading directly to S3. You can do multi file uploads by setting the file input to “multiple” and looping through each of the files, making mulitple submissions via AJAX. To do this you need to set up CORS on the bucket you want to upload to, otherwise you’ll be denied on the grounds of it being a cross-site script. It can be accomplished, as I’ve just got it working on my own project.

I am trying to follow, but not sure how exactly he proposes to use an AJAX to make it work. Does the form will be on AJAx request page and I just feed file names to it?

Can someone familiar with an issue can please explain it to me more thoroughly or direct me to the alternative solution(s)?

Comment: If the web server running the PHP is an EC2 instance , please do not include the key and secret key in the sourcecode. You can simply assign the EC2 instance a IAM Role, then you can call the SDK without supplying any credentials.

Comment: This prototype is just to get the desired functionality, final version will be secured for sure. Now, do you have anything to ad regarding the question itself? :)

Comment: I have spent full day to make this work. I have did a PHP script for my own reference and demo. Hope it helps: https://github.com/jinjie/s3-client-upload-demo

Answer (score 0):

You should use `multiple="multiple"` and also use `name="file[]"`.

Try using:

```
<form action="http://<?= $my_bucket ?>.s3.amazonaws.com/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="hidden" name="key" value="${filename}" />
    <input type="hidden" name="acl" value="public-read" />
    <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Credential" value="<?= $access_key; ?>/<?= $short_date; ?>/<?= $region; ?>/s3/aws4_request" />
    <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Algorithm" value="AWS4-HMAC-SHA256" />
    <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Date" value="<?=$iso_date ; ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="Policy" value="<?=base64_encode($policy); ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="X-Amz-Signature" value="<?=$signature ?>" />
    <input type="hidden" name="success_action_redirect" value="<?= $success_redirect; ?>" /> 
    <input type="file" name="file[]" multiple="multiple" />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

Comment: I have latest sdk and trying to test it and ran into "Class 'AmazonS3' not found" , what version of aws sdk is this code for? Also, my credentials are in ini file as per sdk instructions, do I need to put them into sdk.class.php? Do I also need to load sdk.class.php separately - I though loading autoload was sufficient?

Comment: Also, on submit doesn't it move the files to a temp folder on server? I need it to upload directly to S3 without uploading anything to my server.

Comment: @Acidon the temp files are deleted after the upload, This is how php works with upload, There is no other way to do this, You could upload the file twice, but we dont want to do that, so we have to use temp file....

Comment: @Acidon make sure you have to composer sdk, and the regular sdk you download from the website!

Comment: That's the whole point of my question is to have it uploading directly to S3 bypassing uploading to server completely. As far as I understand, the code in my original post is a working solution that does just that, only for a single file. And my question is how to enable multi upload for that solution or an alternative method that will do a direct upload to S3...

Comment: @Acidon I see what you mean now, I have updated my answer, Please check!

Answer (score 0):

you can encode files to base64 string formats using btoa() and send it to your server as an array 
`[{"base64encodedFile 1",....,"base64encodedFile n"}]` 
in one ajax request. on your server you can loop through the array, decode them back and send it to s3 one by one as an input stream.
I have done this in java, and it worked fine.

ajax :

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/upload",
    data: [{"base64encodedFile 1",....,"base64encodedFile n"}],
    dataType: "json",
    success: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
      // uploaded
    },
    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
      // error
    }
});
```

server side pseudo code:

```
foreach(item in array) {
    decodedFile = base64Decode(item)
    InputStream fis = new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedFile)
    setMetaData() // such as content length, max-age , ...
    PutObjectRequest pro = new PutObjectRequest(getBUCKET_NAME(), 
    fileName, fis, metadata)
    por.setCannedAcl(CannedAccessControlList.PublicRead)
    s3Client.putObject(por)
}
```